# Shirat HaYam Trop: Which Phrases?

Tags: song-poetry, beshalach, trop-cantillation

Which phrases in Shirat HaYam are read with the special 'shirah' trop? (Inspired by [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1918/which-parts-of-the-chazon-haftorah-get-sad-tune-eicha-trop) question.)

Comment: approx 8 pesukim that have Hashem's name in them. There is one exception though

Comment: You mean only the pesukim with God's name in them are read with a special tune?

Comment: What is the exception, and can you provide any sources for what you say?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi anonymous guest! This looks like it has the potential to be a good, full answer. Please flesh it out and cite sources.

Answer (score 6):

Based in my Mesora - which I got from my father:

The special tune starts before the Shira. It is already used for Posuk 14:29 - the Posuk before וַיּוֹשַׁע

```
וְהַמַּיִם לָהֶם חֹמָה, מִימִינָם וּמִשְּׂמֹאלָם
```

Note: this phrases is already mentioned in Pasuk 22 - but there it is sung normally.

Then comes the actual Shira, where each Posuk with Hashem's name gets sung with the special Shira trop.

That's true until 3 Psukim before the end:

- Pasuk 17 -  תְּבִאֵמוֹ, וְתִטָּעֵמוֹ בְּהַר נַחֲלָתְךָ - is read normally.
- Pasuk 18 - Hashem Yimloch - is read with the Shira trop, as expected.
- Pasuk 19 - כִּי בָא סוּס פַּרְעֹה is read normally until the last phrase `הָלְכוּ בַיַּבָּשָׁה, בְּתוֹךְ הַיָּם` which has the "end of the song" nigun.

But we're not done yet - Miriam's Shira is also sung with the Shira trop - i.e. the end of Passuk 21:

```
  שִׁירוּ לַה' כִּי-גָאֹה גָּאָה, סוּס וְרֹכְבוֹ רָמָה בַיָּם
```

Comment: FWIW, I don't remember ever hearing the last phrase of pasuk 19 read in the song tune. I've also heard differing customs regarding 14:29 and 14:22- I once heard someone lein both instances in the song-tune, and in my yeshiva they leined both in the regular trop. But I've heard many places sing the second instance, as is mentioned here

Comment: I know someone whose tradition is that 14:22 gets the special one but 14:29 is read normally, because in 22 חומה is spelled Malei.

Comment: I was told that the first והמים להם חומה is also sung with the shira trop. I have also heard ובמשה עבדו, which leads into the shira, sung with the special tune.

Answer (score 1):

14:29 
Second cadence only - מימנם ומשמאלם

14:31
Second cadence only - ויאמנו בה׳ ובמשה עבדו

15:1-3 - broken like this:
First cadence: אשירה... גאה
Second cadence: סוס... בים
First cadence: עזי... לישועה
Second cadence: זה... וארממנהו
First cadence: ה׳... מלחמה
Second cadence: ה׳ שמו

15:6
First cadence: ימינך... בכח
Second cadence: ימינך... אויב

15:11 - two possibilities
Either:
First cadence: מי־כמכה...בקדש
Second cadence: נורא... פלא
Or:
First cadence: מי־כמכה... ה׳
Second cadence: מי כמכה... קדש
Second cadence again: נורא... פלא

15:16
First cadence: עד... ה׳
Second cadence: עד... קנית

15:18
Second cadence only

15:21
First cadence - שירו... גאה
Second cadence - סוס... בים (this is the last one, I sometimes conclude on a 5-1 instead of a 2-1)

Some people also have a tradition to do this melody for the Journeys sections of Numbers:

10:15-16, 19-20, 23-24, and 26:27

33:11-12, 17-18, 19-20, 21-22, 23-24, 25-26, 27-28, 29-30, 31-32, 33-34, 35-36, 41-42, 43-44, and 45-46

Those verses are always done in pairs,  with the first verse being the first cadence and the second being the second cadence.

Comment: How do you know any of this? Or more importantly, why should anyone here who doesn't know you take your word for it?

Comment: Could you add some explanation of your terminology, the terms first and second cadence?