# What are the rules regarding which verses in the Tocacha (Vayikra 26:14-46) should be read in a loud voice?

Tags: torah-reading, loud-quiet, bechukosai

I am a Ba'al Kri'ah (Torah reader). I have heard various versions regarding protocol for reading these verses. My custom has been to read all the verses in this section in a low voice except for the last one (v 46). In some other shuls, I have heard this scenario:

- Verses 14:33 soft voice
- Verses 34-35 loud
- Verses 36-41 soft voice
- Verse 42 loud
- Verse 43 soft voice
- Verses 44-46 loud

Is there a standard format? To me, multiple switching back and forth in the middle confuses the congregation and me, as well :-)

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1918/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30076/759\

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59139/759

Answer (score 2):

See the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן עח - הלכות קריאת ספר תורה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0077_L2) in סעיף ד where he mentions all instances of where the Ba'al Kri'ah (Torah reader) needs to lower his voice.

Regarding Bechukosai he says:

> **גַם הַקְּלָלוֹת שֶׁבְּפָּרָשַׁת בְּחֻקֹּתַי** וּפָרָשַׁת כִּי תָבֹא קוֹרִין בְּקוֹל נָמוּךְ. **וְאֶת הַפָּסוּק
>    *וְזָכַרְתִּי אֶת בְּרִיתִי יַעֲקֹב* קוֹרִין בּקוֹל רָם. וְאַחַר כָּךְ הַפָּסוּק *וְהָאָרֶץ תֵּעָזֵב וְגוֹ'* נָמוּךְ, וְאַף גַּם זֹאת בְּקוֹל רָם עַד הַסוֹף.** וּבְפָרָשַׁת כִּי תָּבֹא לְיִרְאָה אֶת הַשֵּׁם הַנִּכְבָּד עַד סוֹף הַפָּסוּק בְּקוֹל רָם, וְאַחַר כָּךְ נָמוּךְ. וְאַף גַּם זֹאת, בְּקוֹל רָם עַד הַסוֹף. וּבְפָרָשַׁת כִּי תָבוֹא, לְיִרְאָה אֶת הַשֵׁם הַנִכְבָּד עַד סוֹף הפָּסוּק, בְּקוֹל רָם, וְאַחַר כָּךְ נָמוּךְ עַד וְאֵין קוֹנֶה.‏