# Why are we quiet during the Tochachah?

Tags: minhag, torah-reading, rebuke-tochacha

It is a widespread minhag (Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 78:4, though [by no means do all communities do this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59139/for-purposes-of-how-a-torah-reader-reads-tochacha-where-does-it-start-and-end#comment225001_59139)) that during the Tochachah of Bechukosai (Vayikra 26) and Ki Savo (Devarim 28), the reader reads this section [quietly and quickly](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59139/9682).

Nevertheless, the Midrash (Koheles Rabbah 8:7 in Warsaw numbering) notes that some Amoraim disapproved of this practice (translation follows Eitz Yosef and Matnos Kehunah):

> רבי לוי בן פנטי קרא את ארוריא קדם רבי הונא וגמגם בהון אמר ליה אשמע קליך דלית אינון קללות תוכחות אינון
>
> R’ Levi ben Panti read the curses before R’ Huna, and he mumbled them. He said to him: Let me head your voice, for they are not curses; they are rebukes.

R’ Huna clearly held that we should not mumble during the Tochachah (as an inspiration to do Teshuvah - Yefeh Anaf). Granted that we don’t necessarily pasken a Midrash, but what is wrong with his logic that many have the minhag not to follow it?

It is unclear to me whether R’ Levi accepted R’ Huna’s opinion. If anyone can prove to me that R’ Levi continued this practice in spite of R’ Huna’s psak, perhaps we could argue that we follow R’ Levi.

In respect to the line opening by saying he was reading the “curses” - while that is Artscroll’s translation, Eitz Yosef translates it as “rebuke.”

Comment: He said אשמע קליך that we should hear the voice, which is not _clearly held that we should raise our voices_. Just that it should be audible. Furthermore, Rabbi Levi mumbled it, which is not the same thing as reading it clearly and audibly, if quietly. || Maybe they are instead following R. Levi who evidently disagreed with him. || _but what is wrong with his logic_ What logic? They are curses! What does ארור mean?

Comment: @mevaqesh You are correct on the first point - I misspoke. On the second point - that’s where the Midrash ends, so it’s unclear whether R’ Levi accepted R’ Huna’s ruling. On the third point - I assumed ארור was used in line with R’ Levi’s intention of reading it quietly, while R’ Huna disagreed as to the intention of the pesukim.

Comment: How is ארור not a curse? (ALso what does he think that tokhekha means) Quite frankly I have no idea what R. Huna is talking about. Unless we know what he is talking about, it seems reasonable to not reckon with his opinion.

Comment: @mevaqesh Generally speaking, *tokhakha* is understood to be an attempt at correcting someone from doing an improper behavior (i.e. prevention), as opposed to an after the fact condemnation.

Comment: @mevaqesh Furthermore, it's a pretty well-established practice of traditional Jewry to reckon with its sages' opinions even when we don't understand fully yet their reasoning.

Comment: @mevaqesh You misunderstood what I said. As R’ Levi was the one reading, and interpreting, the passage as curses, the Midrash says he was reading the ארוריא. R’ Huna disagrees with that appellation and says so himself.

Comment: I am not sure how your comment relates to any of mine. I can only guess that your intent, based on how you may have (mis)understood the Midrash. The Midrahs states: רבי לוי בן פנטי קרא את ארוריא קדם רבי הונא וגמגם בהון אמר ליה אשמע קליך דלית אינון קללות תוכחות אינון. The narrator refers to arrurim that he read. R. Huna asserted that they were not klalot, but tohkekhot. The description of arrurim was not that of R. Levi, but of the narrator. The question is whether arrurim are klalot or tokhekhot.

Comment: @mevaqesh I understand. What I was trying to suggest is that the narrator picked the word ארור to reflect R’ Levi’s view he was presently discussing. However, I can hear your reading also.

Comment: Note that the precious line of the Midrash states: קהלת רבה (וילנא) פרשה ח 
דתנינן בברכות קורא ומפסיק בקללות אינו מפסיק אלא אחד קורא את כולן so earlier, the narrator of the Midrash casually refers to it as curses. Similarly, elsewhere the Talmud refers to it as klalot (e.g. Megillah 25b and 31a). So while it is impossible to know why a particular people weren't concerned with one difficult to undersrstand opinion in an aggadic Midrash, the fact that it seems to contradict the Talmud, might be more than enough reason.